# How to install ColdFusion on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, coldfusion

I tried installing ColdFusion on my Ubuntu 16.04 with the following commands.
But I'm unable to install it.

Commands used for installation are these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo ./ColdFusion_11_WWE_linux64.bin
```

After running this command I got an error **command not found**

Answer (score -1):

It appears ColdFusion 2016 is not officially supported on Ubuntu 16.04. Based on the system requirements specified by ColdFusion, I would recommend not using Ubuntu 16.04, but use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 15.04 instead.

*From [System requirements for ColdFusion 2016](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/standard/system-requirements.html) on Linux (Ubuntu highlighted
in bold):*

> 32-bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.X (up to v6.5), **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,
>   Ubuntu 15.04**
>
> 64-bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.0 (up
>   to v7.2), SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12, **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Ubuntu
>   15.04**, CentOS Linux 7

Comment: Please edit your question explicitly state what you mean here. And what actions do you recommend that the poster should take?

Comment: I believe tsqware is saying that CF2016 isn't supported on 16.04. It may or may not work. It's untested.

Comment: It appears ColdFusion 2016 is not officially supported on Ubuntu 16.04. 

Based on the system requirements specified by ColdFusion, I would recommend not using Ubuntu 16.04, but use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or 15.04 instead.

Comment: FWIW, CF2018 adds support for Ubuntu 16.04. It was released in beta, today: https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2018/04/public-beta-for-adobe-coldfusion-2018-release-and-adobe-coldfusion-builder-2018-release/